# Is there a way to force grub2 to load a specific option by pressing a key during the loading process?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

So I'm having a dualboot system, with default linux and windows as an option. I want to be able to press one button (for example, "w") while pc is loading, so grub2 would autochoose windows to boot it. Right now I need to choose an option by pressing arrows, and it isn't very convinient imo. Is it possible to configure such behaviour? The only thing I've found so far is configuring more menu entries.

Comment: I don't need it, I want it stay the same way, just being able to choose an alternate option by pressing a single button.

Comment: Providing OS & release details can always be helpful; as you've given no stack details... so we are likely to assume the older-less flexible `grub` that may have fewer options given our suggestions have to work on all versions (*as you've provided no specifics*).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this: I installed grub-customizer, and copied with it an existing menu entry for booting windows into a new one "win_hotkey". It created entry in "/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/custom", that boots windows. It looks like this:

```
menuentry "win_hotkey"{
    insmod part_gpt
    ...
}
```

So I have edited it into this:

```
menuentry "win_hotkey" --hotkey=7 {
    insmod part_gpt
    ...
}
```

After it I used "sudo update-grub". Now, when grub is loaded, pressing 7 loads windows. However, you can't just hold 7 from powering on pc, it will boot default option. Guess this is the most you can do with grub.